# React native hook does not reload information

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am new to React Native and was trying to make some experiences with hooks. In my app I want to refresh a wifi name when I click on a button. I know this can be done without using the refresh button, but it goes against what I am trying to learn.

The problem here is that when I click the button to refresh the variable unreloaded_netInfo, it does change, because console.log shows the changes, but the value in the Text element does not. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any help.

I have this code

```js
<View style={styles.container}>

   <Text>Wifi name: {unreloaded_netInfo.details.ssid}</Text>
              
   <Button onPress={reloadWifiName} title="refresh" color='#042417'/>
            
</View>
```

reloadWifiName:

```js
 const netInfo = NetInfo.useNetInfo();
 const [unreloaded_netInfo, setNetInfoReload] = useState(netInfo);
 const reloadWifiName = () => {
  let aux=unreloaded_netInfo;

  if(netInfo.type=="wifi") 
  {
    aux.details.ssid=netInfo.details.ssid;
    setNetInfoReload(aux); 
  }
  else setNetInfoReload(netInfo); 
  
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use setNetInfoReload(), React only does a shallow comparison i.e == instead of ===, in order to decide whether to re-render or not. You should try to clone the aux object and update setNetInfoReload() with the cloned object

Comment: This was the problem, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You could like this to declare one metaData variable
const [metaData, setMetaData] = useState(false).
When your state data update at that time also please update metaData value.

```
setNetInfoReload(aux)
setMetaData(! metaData)
```